# openshift email sends from terminal but not from php

Tags: php, email, openshift

I'm using OpenShift and I have problem sending email.

It works fine when logged in via ssh, for eg:

```
echo “Test from Postfix” | mail -s “Test1″ me@yahoo.com
```

However if I want to send an email from php code like this:

```
if (mail ('me@yahoo.com', "Test Postfix", "Test mail from postfix", "From: somebody@example.com"))
  echo "mail sent succesfully";
else 
  echo "couldn't send mail";
```

It writes "mail sent succesfully", but no email arrives :(
Tried without header too, but it's the same.

Checked the settings for **smtp**, **sendmail_path**, **sendmail_from** and **smtp_port**, both with `php -i` and `phpinfo()`. They are the same:

- smtp_port=25
- sendmail_path=*(the path that I get with which sendmail)*
- smtp=localhost (also tried with ini_set("SMTP", "smtp.mysmtp.com")).

error.log contains no error.
I can't find the email.logs.

Can you suggest some solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you need a real sender account in order to make it. That's probably why the other answers suggest plugins/libraries. So you need to provide not only a valid SMTP server, but also an account and pass. Agreed however, that it lacks information about the mail *not* being sent.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommmed checking out the following StackOverflow question: [Can't send email through openshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23064765/cant-send-email-through-openshift)

It sorted everything out for me, and you can define all the variables using the PHPMailer. I spent a few hours trying to do what you were trying to do with PHP within Openshift, but found this plugin solved it almost immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Could be getting caught in the outgoing spam filter, depending on the content etc.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin WP Mail SMTP was a solution for me. 
Read the howtos here: http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-send-email-in-wordpress-using-the-gmail-smtp-server/