# Can't send email through openshift

Tags: php, email, openshift

I have website hosted at OpenShift. I tried to send mail using mail function of php. It just returned true, but no mail is received to whom I had sent.
Please tell me procedure for sending the mail.

I searched a lot but none of the options worked.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After searching alot I came up with the following solution:

Step 1: Create account on [mailgun](https://mailgun.com/) and add your OpenShift application url.

Step 2: Download the PhpMailer library from [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and add it to your php folder

Step 3: Go through this sample [example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#a-simple-example)

Step 4: Replace username and password with the credentials you got after adding domain to mailgun.

Step 5: Done!

Comment: @aagam94 At step 4, in what file to put the sample example code. (filename) Thanks!

Comment: @leontalbot :  You need to put those sample code where you want to send a mail

Comment: I got the message `The domain is unverified and requires DNS configuration. Log in to your control panel to view required DNS records.`. Control panel says I have to config `TXT records`. How to do that in Openshift?